# Users field manually delete from database cache problem

Tags: users, database, caching

i manually remove  a column of field_data_field_about in database belongs to some users. and this field is user field. And after in admin panel i edit this user which i delete this user column from database. But this user about value is shown there. Then i Clear All Caches then i come back to edit this user the about value is gone.

How can i disable cache for users fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why you'd want to remove a column from a field table but just looking at your problem as is, a way by which you can disable caching of field values in the `cache_field` bin is by letting Drupal know that you don't want values for the field instances attached to a given entity type to be cached at all.

You can do this by implementing `hook_entity_info_alter()` from a custom module and setting the `field cache` key for the `user` entity as shown below:

```
function mymod_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['user']['field cache'] = FALSE;
}
```

You might find the documentation of `hook_entity_info` [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7) useful. You might also want to lookup the definition of `field_attach_load()` from [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7).

Comment: users has mobile field and i send sms to this mobile number when users reset this or delete this number in admin i edit this user but the mobil number not gone when i clear cahche the mobile number is gone. İs this a problem or not?

Comment: should i disable cahce for this field or not disable it i don't know.

Comment: in my second comment i want to say users modify number on their profile after i'm admin in admin panel i test this user if number is gone.